# Shell command to determine the similarity of two images on macOS

Tags: images, macos, comparison

I’m looking for a tool/software that will compare two bitmap images (pixel graphics) of same size and shape (aspect ratio and orientation) and return their rate of similarity (e.g. in %).

Should run as a terminal command on macOS.

Comment: I think this needs more criteria. How many % do you consider an image that was flipped? No pixel will match, since they all changed their location. Still, the operation to get there is very simple.

Comment: How many % do you consider an image that was 1000x1000 and then scaled down to 100x100? Is the difference 99% because 99% of the pixels are lost, or is it 0% because it's the same image, just scaled?

Comment: The images are basically the same (size etc.), but there are some minor changes from image to image that I want to determine or ignore in my script. E.g. a small ring around an object on images might pulsate a bit. If this is the only difference the tool should tell a difference of 5% e.g. If additionally some text on the image differs, the tool should determine another (higher) percentage.

Comment: I've edited the question to grasp the details. Please check whether you agree to the edit.

Comment: What you need should be easily possible. I have implemented such a program myself already. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with macOS and don't do cross platform development.